# Extracting text after specific word

Tags: regex

I want to match all text after a given string with a regex. In this case, the text after the "From:" including the entire text body. Each piece of text may contain more than one 'From' segment(Email body).Any suggestions most welcome.

```
From: tonyt@gmail.com  
Sent: 03 September 2019 12:54  
To: eddie@gmail.com  
Subject: blahblah  

Dear Eddie, Blah Blah  

From: eddie@gmail.com  
Sent: 04 September 2019 12:54  
To: tonyt@gmail.com  
Subject: blahblah  

Dear Tony, Blah Blah
```

**Desired output**

**Match 1** 
tonyt@gmail.com
Sent: 03 September 2019 12:54
To: eddie@gmail.com
Subject: blahblah

Dear Eddie, Blah Blah

**Match 2**
eddie@gmail.com
Sent: 04 September 2019 12:54
To: tonyt@gmail.com
Subject: blahblah

Dear Tony, Blah Blah

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^From: (?:(?!^From: ).)+
```

in `singleline` and `multiline` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/DOAail/2/).